# Is there an mycrypt mode that doesnt change?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mcrypt

I am using mcrypt to store credit card numbers in a table. I am also using the same credit card numbers to check if the user has already applied the coupon code.

The problem that I am facing is that the mcrypt  string always changes, when the user posts their credit card number on the checkout page.

Is there an mcrypt method that does not change the string each time?

By the way, I am using codeigniter's encryption class to cipher the credit card numbers

Any help would be really appricated

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Don't play with credit cards, use third party service like PayPal, Stripe or AuthorizeNet. Full stop.

Answer (score 3):

> **Notice: storing and processing credit card data is not recommended
>   providing you know little about security and encryption**

The function you are using outputs different string but you can check them if the input was indentical.

When it comes to functions that return "same strings" everytime, you can use SHA256 hashing function:

```
<?php
   $string = "123";
   $hash = hash( 'sha256', $string );
   $user_input = "123";

   if(hash( 'sha256', $user_input ) == $hash){
        echo "Correct credit card number";
   } else {
        echo "Did not find a match";
   }
?>
```

Read more about the hash() method [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)

Comment: **First off, I 1000% agree that OP should not be handling or storing sensitive data.** It's near-trivial to bruteforce 16-char passwords hashed with simple SHA256, and it will be orders of magnitude easier to get 16-digit numbers. If we're going to persist in this horrifying endeavour we should at least use a reasonably secure hashing method like [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).